# UICollectionView With Multiple Cells - Is It Possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In the process of discovering the **`UICollectionView`** as a replacement for the `UITableView`.

I have created a very basic collection that contains a single `section` and single `Cell`, but displaying multiple values that is amended into a `NSString`. I believe it's a clunky way of doing things.
Take a look at the following image to get an understanding what I have done and how I have done it:

[image: Single Cell]

What I would like to know, is it possible to create a **`Collection View`** that uses multiple `Cells` that I can use to contain the values. Check out the following graphic to give you an idea on what I would like to achieve:

[image: Desired Collection]

Possible??

Comment: yes its possible, you will change the cell only width, use single cell change only width.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - good to hear.

Comment: It's possible, but I'd clearly put various labels instead of one to keep an alignment.